# Throw FileLoadException or just IOException

Tags: c#, exception, file

I am writing an app and I want to load a file based on a path provided by the user. I check the extension of the file and when the extension does not match anything I recognize I want to throw an exception.

I could throw an `IOException`. But, I figured there could be a more detailed exception derived from that. So I looked at MSDN and found [`FileLoadException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileloadexception.aspx). The name suggests that my error would fit in this category, but.... when I look on MSDN it says: "Represents the error that occurs when a Assembly file is found but cannot be loaded." and "The exception that is thrown when a managed assembly is found but cannot be loaded." That is absolutely not what is the case with my error.

So what is the question then? Well, I wonder if the documentation actually means that the exception is meant to be thrown for this purpose only or that they just mean that *they* throw that exception in that specific case, but do not really specify when others should throw it.

On the [`IOException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ioexception.aspx) page on MSDN it does advice to use `FileLoadException` where appropriate:

> `IOException` is the base class for exceptions thrown while accessing information using streams, files and directories.
>
> The Base Class Library includes the following types, each of which is a derived class of `IOException`:
>
> - DirectoryNotFoundException
> - EndOfStreamException
> - FileNotFoundException
> - FileLoadException
> - PathTooLongException
>
> Where appropriate, use these types instead of IOException.

Summarized: In case of an unknown file extension, should I throw an `IOException` or a `FileLoadException` (I do not want to define my own exception).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should throw `IOException`, and never throw `FileLoadException` which is very specific and "technical" (whereas your exception should be "application oriented"). Try to analyze `FileLoadException` type with `Reflector` (in mscorlib), you'll see that it's only used for the purpose defined in the msdn. Then imagine one day your code used in a "plugin context", how will react the host program catching a `FileLoadException` meaning an assembly failed to load properly ...

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't throw an exception that is documented to be of a very specific use-case and might confuse others.

If you can't define a new exception, stick with `IOException`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So is `FileLoadException` only thrown in the case of an assembly not being able to load?

Comment: I can't say for sure, but it seems like that's the only use that it's intended for.

Answer (score 2):

`FileLoadException` wouldn't seem to be a good fit, because it's specifically for assemblies.

`IOException` is suitable, but it feels *very* generic and wont let callers handle it gracefully, distinguishing it from more general errors.

If you really have to throw an exception here, consider [`NotSupportedException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notsupportedexception.aspx), which identifies an attempt to perform an operation which your object does not support, in this case loading a file format you don't recognise.

Comment: Surely NotSupportedException, when used in this way, is just as useless as System.Exception?

Comment: All exception handling requires context to be useful. The purpose of specifying this exception is to make it distinguishable from more general IOException instances possible in this context. It seems quite a fitting choice when the action requested is specifically not supported!

Answer (score 2):

Good practice is to define your own exceptions: derive one from whether Exception or any other more specific Exception subclass.

This will save your time during testing as well as provide you more information with future feedback: you can differ between some exceptions that are not handled in you code and those your own business logic throws based on your specific rules.

Speaking of this case, I advise you create `FileExtensionException` derived from `IOException`. This will pretty much ease you code: you won't have to check error message providing separate `catch` block for new exception type.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a case of just validating the user data.

Why would you want to throw an exception and just not inform the user that he provided an extension that is not recognized by your application?

If you're using the `OpenFileDialog` you can even use the `OpenFileDialog.Filter` in order to allow the user to only select a file with an extension supported by your application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The reason I do not want to do that is because I cannot make any assumptions on the user interface.